# How do I force pip to install a package directly from the Internet not local cache?

Tags: python-3.x, caching, pip

I was installing the package ibm_db using the command:

```
pip3 install ibm_db
```

However, there was a power outage and the installation stopped midway.
Now, the package is available in my system:

```
pip3 list --local | grep ibm
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
ibm-db (3.0.1)
```

But when I try to import it, it doesn't work.

```
>>> import ibm_db
>>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ibm_db
```

I'm suspecting that something went wrong with the package installation, but every time I try to reinstall (uninstalling, then installing it again) it it uses the locally cached version now, and the problem continues.

I would like to try reinstalling the package straight from the internet, without having to use my local cache, but I don't want to clear the entire local cache.

Answer (score 18):

https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching

```
pip install --no-cache-dir …
```

PS. But I doubt the problem is in cache. After uninstalling and installing packages again everything must be ok. If it's not — the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right. It turns out the problem was that the virtual environment in which I was developing the application was broken after being copied to another folder. pip3 installed the packages to the wrong virtual environment, while the 'python3' version being used while in the current virtual environment was the system provided version as opposed to the virtual environment specified version.

Comment: Python virtual environments aren't relocatable.

Comment: Yes, I eventually learned that virtualenv doesn't officially support relocating virtual environments. I did manage to relocate it and repair the environment though, after a few hacks. Incidentally, is there a standard way of shipping a complete python project with all of its necessary libraries? Assuming that all of the libraries are written entirely in pure python?

Comment: Shipping of "all necessary libraries" would be either (a) build wheels from every dependency and ship them, or (b) If end-user does not want to install python, do "a" and ship it with portable python distribution. I usually also include some "install.bat" for non-experienced users.

Comment: @LusayoNyondo https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+standalone+script